# Как равномерно разделить элементы на группы в заданных пропорциях?

Tags: java, массивы, математика

Имеется массив/перечислимый объект некоторых элементов. Есть три группы, на которые нужно разделить этот массив элементов в заданных пропорциях А, B, C (A+B+C=1). То есть если всего элементов N, то в первой группе окажется N*A элементов, во второй N*B элементов, в третьей - N*С. Причем элементы попали в эти группы наиболее равномерным (насколько это возможно) образом, то есть вероятности попадания элемента в любую из групп одинаковы.

Необходимо написать алгоритм этого разделения. Желательно на Java.

Условное дано:

```java
double A; //доля первой группы
double B; //доля второй группы
double C; //доля третьей группы
int[] items; // элементы
```

В своих изысканиях я придумал следующий алгоритм. По заданной доле и количеству элементов вычисляется, сколько элементов будет в группе. По этому количеству определяется шаг, с которым будет проходиться список элементов. Алгоритм с конца проходит список извлекая из него элементы через указанный шаг, и складывая его в накапливаемую группу. Функция возвращает выделенную группу и применяется к оставшимся элементам уже с другим значением доли.

```java
private static List<Integer> take(List<Integer> items, int count) {
        double step = (double) items.size() / count;
        int size = items.size();
        List<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int index = (int) Math.round(size - 1 - i * step);
            Integer item = items.remove(index);
            res.add(0, item);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Алгоритм в целом работает, но качество его равномерности математически оценить сложно. Визуально получается так:

1. Для пяти элементов

```
A = 55,00% B = 35,00% C = 10,00%

 0  1  2  3  4 
 C  A  A  B  A 
---------------
    A  A     A 
          B    
 C
```

2. Для десяти элементов

```
A = 55,00% B = 35,00% C = 10,00%

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 B  A  A  C  A  B  A  A  B  A 
------------------------------
    A  A     A     A  A     A 
 B              B        B    
          C
```

3. Для десяти элементов

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 B  A  C  A  A  B  A  B  A  B  A  B  A  C  A  A  B  A  B  A 
------------------------------------------------------------
    A     A  A     A     A     A     A     A  A     A     A 
 B              B     B     B     B              B     B    
       C                                C
```

Прошу сообщество попытаться оценить качество такого решения и предложить варианты улучшения или альтернативы. Возможно, такая задача уже решена математиками или некоторыми программистами.

Comment: что такое "равномерно"?

Comment: Вообще-то первая ваша задача с неоднозначным ответом - как получить количества элементов в группах, как округлять пропорции,

Comment: Перемешать случайным образом и выбрать первые NA в первую группу, NB во вторую, остальное в третью (очевидно, что придется округлять количество до целого). Или разработать *точный однозначный критерий* того, что такое "равномерность", и тогда можно будет говорить о чем-то еще...

Answer (score 0):

Ладно, будем считать что целочисленные количества элементов вы уже получили.

Теперь используйте трехмерный алгоритм Брезенхэма ([вот какая-то реализация](https://gist.github.com/yamamushi/5823518)), только вместо вывода трехмерных точек делайте вывод того элемента, чья координата увеличивается (т.е. в момент `point[1] += y_inc;` выводите `B` и т.п.)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то проблема в том, что в первую группу попадает 55% элементов, во вторую 35 %, в 3 10%, а должно быть примерно 33% в каждой группе.
Есть две идеи :

1. Хранить 3 группы чисел в 3х разных массивах с размером 33 % от общего числа элементов.
2. Предусмотреть для рандомного распределения элементов условие  что если группа А больше установленного размера, то элемент рандомно добавляется либо в В, либо в С. И так для каждой группы.

Comment: Совсем наоборот. Как раз необходимо, чтобы в группы числа попадали в группы в соответствии с заданными пропорциями. В приложенном примере это пропорции: A/B/C = 55/35/10.